# About alarmManager and perfomance/battery issue

Tags: android, performance, alarmmanager, android-alarms, reminders

Android beginner here:
i'm writing a pills' reminder app using alarmManager, but i was wondering if i need to implement a daily scheduler and a database to store the alarms that don't need to set off today, or does the alarmManager do everything by itself, avoiding excessive performance issues and battery drain? i'm asking it because, let's say that we have 30 alarms per 30 pills every week, i think that having all the alarms "ticking" when i only need to take a couple of pills a day is very expensive.
I tried to read the documentation but it's seem very generic.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use AlarmManager to set repeating reminders, the [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) recommends AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating() which allows you to set intervals like AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY to repeat everyday and synchronizes repeating alarms from multiple apps to fire at the same time. If you want to consider other options instead of AlarmManager you should watch this talk from Joanna Smith https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7maNuWjL3Wc